# TypeScript variable that hold a class instance that extends a base class

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I want to have a variable to stores a class instance array, but I want to specify the data type as anything that inherits from a 'base' class. This better demonstrated by example:

```
class Mom { } //Base class
class Son extends Mom { }
class Daughter extends Mom { }

//What is the syntax for this?
let example : <T extends Mom>T[] = [ ]; //This array should store anyting that extends 'Mom'

//The this would be possible
example.push(new Mom());
example.push(new Son());
example.push(new Daughter());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about: `let example = [] as Mom[];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way

```
let example : Array<Mom> = [ ];
```

See **[here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Mom%20%7B%20%7D%20%2F%2FBase%20class%0D%0Aclass%20Son%20extends%20Mom%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0Aclass%20Daughter%20extends%20Mom%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20example%20%3A%20Array%3CMom%3E%20%3D%20%5B%20%5D%3B%20%2F%2FThis%20array%20should%20store%20anyting%20that%20extends%20'Mom'%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FThe%20this%20would%20be%20possible%0D%0Aexample.push(new%20Mom())%3B%0D%0Aexample.push(new%20Son())%3B%0D%0Aexample.push(new%20Daughter())%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(example)%3B)**

Comment: Does this include thing that extend mom? Because it is not very verbose.

Comment: @CameronBell yes everything that is Mom

Answer (score 2):

You can do things like

```
type Shape = Mom | Son | Daughter;
let example:Array<Shape> = new Array<Shape>();
```

Comment: But then I would have to manually add every class that I want. Is there anyway to do this automatically?

Comment: In your case just **Array<Mom>** is fine and Will work.

Comment: you can also do this: 
let example = Shape[] = { .. }